# How to combine two value of two column in a table.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there any way to select data from table like below?

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE fname+" "+lname LIKE '%$name%'
```

For example:

```
fname = "Lady"
lname = "Gaga"
$name = "lady g" is match
```

Just like the facebook search engine, when I input a full name, it will display the result even the full name included non breaking space.

Comment: `+` is arithmetic addition in mysql. it's **NOT** the concatentation operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [**CONCAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) LIKE '%$name%'
```

Comment: thank you so much, but I found another error...when I insert a " ", it will not run all php....

Comment: If you insert `" "` and it does not run the code, the problem may be that you are using `"` to wrap the Query too. Try `' '` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There sure is - you can use the mysql `CONCAT()` function -

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE CONCAT(fname," ",lname) LIKE '%$name%'
```

The `CONCAT()` function can take many arguments, quoted strings are taken as their literal values and field names evaluate to their value from the table being queried. So `fname` and `lname` must be the actual names of the fields in your database.

See [here for some more in-depth documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you need to use `CONCAT()` or `CONCAT_WS()` to concatenate two objects.

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) LIKE '%$name%'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', fname, lname) LIKE '%$name%'
```

- [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `CONCAT` function. Keep in mind this is likely to have poor performance as it wont use indexes correctly.

`SELECT * FROM profile WHERE CONCAT(fname," ",lname) LIKE '%$name%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', fname, lname) LIKE '%' . $name . '%'
```

Remembering to escape the input, of course (or to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)).